# React and Redux - Cannot render one component in another

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a component TrialForm.js and I want to render this in another component called TimelineNodeEditorDrawer.js. I think the problem might be that I use the MuiThemeProvider in both files and material UI might not allow that.

TrialForm.js:

```
class TrialForm extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
}
render(){

...(some code)

var form = <div><SelectField
        value={this.props.pluginType}
        floatingLabelText="Plugin Type"
        maxHeight={300}
        style={pluginStyle}
        onChange={(event, key) => this.props.onChange(plugins[key])} >
        {pluginItems}
        </SelectField>
        {pluginParameters}
        </div>
    } else {
        var form = <div></div>;
    }
    return(
        <MuiThemeProvider>
        {form}
        </MuiThemeProvider>
        )
   }
}

export default TrialForm;
```

TimelineNodeEditorDrawer.js:

```
export default class TimelineNodeEditorDrawer extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
}

render() {
    return (
        <MuiThemeProvider>  

...(some code)

<div className="TimelineNode-Editor-Container"
                style={{height: '100%', width: '100%'}}>
                {(this.props.open) ? 
                <div className="TimelineNode-Editor-Content">
                    <div style={{display: 'flex'}}>
                        <IconButton 
                        disableTouchRipple={true}
                        hoveredStyle={{backgroundColor:
                        CloseBackHighlightColor}}
                        onTouchTap=
                        {this.props.closeTimelineEditorCallback}
                        >{(this.props.open) ? 
                        <CloseDrawer hoverColor=
                        {CloseDrawerHoverColor}/> : null}</IconButton>
                        <Subheader>Timeline/Trial Editor</Subheader>
                    </div>
                    <Divider />
                    <TrialForm id={this.props.id} pluginType={this.props.pluginType} />
                </div> : null}
            </div>
```

For more clarification, here is a screen shot. It is the drawer on the right side. The text fields to the far right should all be under 'Timeline/Trial Editor':
[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNznr.png)

**Edit**
index.js:

```
const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));

injectTapEventPlugin();
ReactDOM.render(
  <MuiThemeProvider>
  <Provider store={store}>
  <App />
  </Provider>
  </MuiThemeProvider>,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

The TrialForm.js and TimelineNodeEditorDrawer.js stay the same except that I removed the MuiThemeProvider and put a div tag instead. If it helps, the entire git repo(without these changes) are [here](https://github.com/jspsych/jsPsych-Redux-GUI)

This is the render of my App.js. I put TrialForm inside TimelineNodeEditorDrawer and now the drawer is back to the width it is supposed to be but I can't see anything from TrialForm. I don't know whether that was a step in the right direction or not.

App.js:

```
    render() {
    return (
        <div className="App" style={{overflowX: 'hidden', height: "100%"}}>
            <div className="appbar-container" style={{height: "20%"}}>
                <Appbar />
            </div>
            <div className="main-container" style={{width: '100%', display: 'flex', height: "80%"}}>
                <TimelineNodeOrganizerDrawer 
                    open={this.state.timelineOrganizerDrawerToggle}
                    width={this.state.timelineOrganizerDrawerWidth}
                    openCallback={this.openTimelineOgranizerDrawer}
                    closeCallback={this.closeTimelineOgranizerDrawer}
                    setWidthCallback={this.setTimelineOrangizerWidth}
                    openTimelineEditorCallback={this.openTimelineEditorDrawer}
                    closeTimelineEditorCallback={this.closeTimelineEditorDrawer}
                />
                <div className="main-body" 
                    style={{width: mainBodyWidth(this.state.timelineOrganizerDrawerToggle, 
                                                this.state.timelineOrganizerDrawerWidth, 
                                                this.state.timelineEditorDrawerToggle),
                     margin: '0 auto',
                    }}
                >
                <Preview />
                </div>
                <TimelineNodeEditorDrawer open={this.state.timelineEditorDrawerToggle} 
                    openTimelineEditorCallback={this.openTimelineEditorDrawer} 
                    closeTimelineEditorCallback={this.closeTimelineEditorDrawer}>
                    <TrialForm open={this.state.timelineEditorDrawerToggle} />
                </TimelineNodeEditorDrawer>
            </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
 }


 export default App;
```

Comment: Why not inject the MuiThemeProvider at the root of your application?

Comment: I tried it right now and got rid of the MuiThemeProviders in other components, but now I'm getting the error  **Failed prop type: Invalid prop `children` of type `array` supplied to `MuiThemeProvider`, expected a single ReactElement.** and **MuiThemeProvider.render(): A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.**

Comment: Can you update your code?

Comment: Why don't you wrap the 2 elements in a div in the root?
return(
        <MuiThemeProvider>
        <div>
{TrialForm}
{TimelineNodeEditorDrawer}
</div>
        </MuiThemeProvider>
        )
   }

Comment: Are you intentionally using hoisting with `var form`? Why don't you pull `var form` in front of the `if-else`?

Comment: @Sulthan Because it is supposed to be a conditional render. It checks whether the item selected is a trial and if the right hand drawer is open.

Comment: @kristiyip The usual way to do this would be `var form; if (...) { form = ... } else { form = ... }`.